# A = matrix(B) = matrix(C)

Tags: matrices

I am trying to write it on latex:

[image]

But i couldn't!
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Load `amsmath` and use the `bmatrix` environment.

Answer (score 3):

As Bernard said, it is simple enough using the `bmatrix` environment.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\Huge
\[
\sigma=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \sigma_{xx} & \sigma_{xy} & \sigma_{xz} \\
    \sigma_{xy} & \sigma_{yy} & \sigma_{yz} \\
    \sigma_{xz} & \sigma_{yz} & \sigma_{zz} \\
  \end{bmatrix}=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \sigma_{xx} & \tau_{xy} & \tau_{xz} \\
    \tau_{xy} & \sigma_{yy} & \tau_{yz} \\
    \tau_{xz} & \tau_{yz} & \sigma_{zz} \\
  \end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

Yields:

[image]

Comment: `amsart` could change a lot the format. Just load `amsmath`.